# I do not understand the working of tfidfvectorizer of sckit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

The formula I know to calculate tf-idf is TF * IDF where TF is the number of times the word occurs in a document D and IDF is Number Of Documents/ Number Of Documents which contains the word + 1.

This is my dataset.
`corpus = [ 'This is the first document.', 'This document is the second document.', 'And this is the third one.', 'Is this the first document?', ]`
Now I calculated td-idf of the word 'document' in document 1, the output was 0.22.
But when I used sckit's tfidf vectorizer, the output was:
1.22314355
The vectorizer I used had the following parameters:
`vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None)` 
Please explain me why is the answer different.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code such that it is easier to troubleshoot and directly answer your question. When I run this with default settings, I get a TF-IDF value of 0.469791.

This is aligned with the [formula](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#:~:text=The%20formula%20that%20is%20used,document%20frequency%20of%20t%3B%20the) in the sklearn documentation for TfidfVectorizer. Note the change that is applied to the formula when `smooth_idf` is set to True (the default)